# Override permissions for Craft Commerce saveProduct controller

Tags: plugins, plugin-craftcommerce, permissions

I'm creating products using a frontend form which submits to `commerce/products/saveProduct` but it only works when I'm logged-in. They're really complicated products which need to be created on-the-fly.

If it were my own plugin controller I was using, then I could just add `protected $allowAnonymous = true;` but as it isn't, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom plugin and point your frontend form to save to its own controller action that allows anonymous access.

That action can either 1) duplicate Commerce's `saveProduct` method, which can be brittle if it changes or 2) start a session from a generic user account that has the proper permissions and [forward](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#forward-detail) the request onto Commerce's `saveProduct` method.